# Sign Up Страница ошибка в sql базы данных

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, регистрация

Цель сделать регистрационную страницу и при вводе данных проверить их и добавить в базу данных sql
При вводе данных и нажатии кнопки "Зарегистрироваться":
Выходит текст: "Вас не удалось зарегистрировать" и данные не записываются в Базу Данных

Вот база данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Когда я из базы данных удалаяю diary всё работает! но мне нужно чтобы всё с diary работало

Код index.php:

```
<?php
    if (array_key_exists("submit", $_POST)) {
        $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'site');
        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            die ('Ошибка подключения к базе данных');
        }
        $error = '';
    
        if(!$_POST['username']){
            $error .= "Имя пользователя обязательна<br>";
        }
    
        if (!$_POST['password']) {
            $error .= "Пароль обязателен";
        }
    
        if ($error != "") {
            $error = "<p>В вашей форме были ошибки:</p>".$error;
        } else{
    
            $query = "SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE username = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['username'])."' LIMIT 1";
    
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                $error = "Такой логин уже занят!";
            }else{
    
                $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['username'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['password'])."')";
                if(!mysqli_query($link,$query)){
                    $error = "<p>Вас не удалось зарегистрировать</p>";
                }else{
                    echo "Вы успешно зарегистрировались";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
    <div class="error">
        <?php
        echo $error;
        ?>
    </div>
    
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Введите логин">
    
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Введите пароль">
    
        <input type='checkbox' name='stayLoggedIn' value=1>
    
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться">
    
    </form>
```

Comment: Во-первых, выводить надо не только своё сообщение, но и сообщение об ошибке, которое вернул сервер. Во-вторых, показывайте собранный текст запроса, который привёл к ошибке.

Comment: Ну и ... через поле пароля тебя очень быстро от-inject-ят.

Comment: Как вывести запрос об ошибке от сервера? md5 шифрование потом добавлю

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php